# How to log every click in iOS App with Flurry

Tags: ios, flurry

How can I log every button click in iOS App with Flurry?
I want to realize click flows in my app.

Comment: You do realize that you're app's performance is going to be seriously affected by doing that?

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate

```
#import "Flurry.h"
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{     
     [Flurry startSession:@"sessionkey"];
     ...   
}
```

and..

```
-(IBAction) Click_Search:(id)sender
{     
     [Flurry logEvent:@"Seach"]; // remain logEvent 
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A valid approach would be to subclass `UIApplication` and overwrite the `-sendEvent:` method
 like follows:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];

    NSSet * allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] > 0) {
        UITouch *touch = [allTouches anyObject];
        if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
             CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.window];
             NSDictionary *params = @{
                 @"touch" : @{
                     @"x" : @(touchLocation.x),
                     @"y" : @(touchLocation.y)
                 }
             };
             [Flurry logEvent:@"Seach" withParameters:params];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to change the `UIApplication` class to be used in `main.m`.
For instance if your `UIApplication` subclass is called `MyApplication`, your main will become

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyApplication class]));
    }
}
```

**DISCLAIMER**
This may drastically affect the performance of your app. Use it wisely.